# Wrapping images on different pages

Tags: wrapfigure

I have some text and I would like to include some images on top of page 2 and page 4 and on the bottom of page 7.
I tried the code below but I could not get the right formatting.
I would be grateful for your help.

```
 \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{extarticle}
 \usepackage{lipsum}


 \begin{document}

 \begin{figure}[p=2,t]
 \centering 
 \includegraphics{a.pdf}
 \end{figure}

 \begin{figure}[p=4,t]
 \centering 
 \includegraphics{b.pdf}
 \end{figure}

 \begin{figure}[p=7,b]
 \centering 
 \includegraphics{c.pdf}
 \end{figure}

 \lipsum[1-500]

 \end{document}
```

Comment: p means a dedicated page for floats, but you can select the page by being clever with \afterpage.

Comment: Do you need to put the graphics in floating environments?    If you know exactly where you want to put your illustrations, then you could just put in manual page breaks and use `\includegraphics` on it's own without the `figure` environments.

Comment: The text and the actual graphics may change so I need a template where the text wraps around the graphics which are in specified places in the report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also pack `\onpage` into the previous `\onpage`, but this way is less confusing.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{extarticle}
 \usepackage{afterpage}
 \usepackage{mwe}

\def\bottomfraction{0.5}% allows bigger figures on bottom of page

 \newcommand{\onpage}[2]% #1 = page, #2 = code
  {\ifnum\value{page}<#1\relax\afterpage{\onpage{#1}{#2}}%
   \else#2\fi}

 \begin{document}

 \onpage{2}{%
 \begin{figure}[t]
 \centering 
 \includegraphics{example-image-a}
 \end{figure}}}%

 \onpage{4}{%
 \begin{figure}[t]
 \centering 
 \includegraphics{example-image-b}
 \end{figure}}}%

 \onpage{7}{%
 \begin{figure}[b]
 \centering 
 \includegraphics{example-image-c}
 \end{figure}}}%

 \lipsum[1-40]

 \end{document}
```