# How to fix figures on specific pages at bottom over page width?

Tags: floats, minipage

I am layouting a program book (using book class and multicols{2}).
I have a number of ads from sponsors that are not related to the text. They are pdfs. I need to bind them in at fix places (irregular) on specific pages covering 1/2 page or 1 page (pagewidth, not textwidth).

I am having a hard time to achieve this. I tried `figure[!b]`, `[H]`, or `[!h]`, and also `minipage[b]`.

With the figure environment, the figures never stay at the same place, cover the text or each other.

With the `minipage` environment I seem not to be able to place them at the very bottom of the page and in whole page width, only in textwidth...

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The flowfram package is mostly used to lay out newsletters.  One can also use an \afterpage loop to wait for a specific page.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285146/wrapping-images-on-different-pages

Comment: Have a look at this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30985/displaying-a-wide-figure-in-a-two-column-document

Comment: You want an image in bottom of page: 1) by page you mean text or paper? 2) what about the height of image and the text height ?

Comment: @Markus please use `@name`  with no space you'll get autocomplete.

Comment: @touhami: 1) page, yes I mean paper. It is an A4 paper, and the sponsor's ad is a landscape A5 format, so it is exactly 1/2 of the paper. This is then not at disposition anymore for the floating text.

Comment: @Augustin: This is the text width, but I need the whole paper.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: The accepted answer in your link doesn't work when I compile it: Instead of graphics on page 2,4, and 7, they are on page 8,9, and 10, at the end of all text.

Comment: The accepted answer from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285146/wrapping-images-on-different-pages should only be 9 pages long.  The original mwe behaves as you described.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: If I add a scaling option to the includegraphics line: \onpage{2}{%
 \begin{figure}[t]
 \centering 
 \noindent\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{UP2016.pdf}
 \end{figure}}%, then I get the images at the right place, however again across the text width and not across paper width. How can I make them fille the ENTIRE lower 50% of a paper, without keeping a empty margin around?

Comment: You can make figures exceed the text area (using lots of negative \hspace and \vspace), but flowfram is better suited for that sort of layout.