# Two column page with different heights

Tags: floats, two-column, ieee-style, height

I am trying to utilise all the whitespace in a two column (ieee) format document.

A set of tables must stay grouped on the same page, thus I've nested them under {table*}. Having done that, I now have some unutilised space marked in red as displayed in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBu3r.png) below.

Is there a way to adjust the height of the right hand side column to fill up the whitespace? Or, could you please suggest an alternative solution?

Thanks,
Gin

[image]

Comment: if you  are prepared to do manual adjustment you can add `\vspace*{-...}` at the column break to bring up the start of the second column.

Comment: Manually, there's all kinds of wonders you can do. Is this for a submission to a journal? If so, they'll probably question it though. Could you provide us with your constraints or limitations?

Comment: Another possibility is to combine a table* and table, or possibly several tables.  Using afterpage you can control what page they all appear on (assuming a clear table queue).  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285146/wrapping-images-on-different-pages/285153?s=11|0.0681#285153

Comment: Thanks for your replies!

Werner, this is for a workshop. There aren't any guidelines apart from keeping the text within column margins.

I will try John's solution for now.

David, this will be my last resort as this solution is very sensitive to edits elsewhere.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the text around the tables like in this example: [Wrap text around a tabular](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49300/wrap-text-around-a-tabular) ?

Comment: BenK, in the end, I have decided to set floats strictly to [t] and played a little bit with \vspace. A case-specific workaround that cascades down on any further modification. Very unadvisable :).