# How to put big equations on a specific page in LaTex?

Tags: equations, page

I wrote two big equations on my thesis by using figure* as

```
\begin{figure*}
\small
\begin{align}
Ax=b
    \label{EQN:5}
\end{align}
\hrulefill
\end{figure*}
```

My problem is, I need the equations on page 3, however, texstudio put them on page 5. How can I put them on the specific page I want? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you please add a full MWE?

Comment: do not use the `figure*` environment. It makes no sense.

Comment: Do you want them to float around? Do they form part of the discussion? Essentially you're interested in a way to force a float (regardless of whether it contains an equation, graphic, paragraph or table) onto a specific page. Correct?

Comment: If you use a `figure` (float) environment then LaTeX will put it where it thinks best. Try putting your equations in some kind of `box` environment, for example a `minipage`.

Comment: @Herbert is probably correct about the `figure*` environment, but you didn't say what document class you're using.  if it is a two-column style, then `figure*` *may* make sense because it specifies a figure that goes across both columns, at the top of the page.  but in that case, it will *always" go on a page later than the one where it is input.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285146/wrapping-images-on-different-pages

Answer (score 3):

see if package `cuted` can help you:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
%%%%    key package
\usepackage{cuted}

%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{strip}
\[
here - is - huge - equation - which - need - space - width = of - width - of - both - columns
\]
\end{strip}
    \newpage
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\lipsum[2-4]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have not given an MWE wich we can run to see exactly what your problem is.

Do not put your equations in a float (e.g., `figure`) environment which LaTeX will place where it thinks best. What's the problem with putting them unadorned in your general text? Perhaps you should put them within a `box` (e.g., a `minipage`) so they don't move around or break at a page boundary.

Answer (score 1):

With the following code, the big display goes to page 4 instead of page 3, where we'd like it to go.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[numbers]{kantlipsum} % for mock text

\begin{document}

\title{A paper}
\author{A. Uthor}
\date{}

\maketitle

\kant[1-3] % fill page 1
\kant*[4]
\begin{equation} % an equation
a=a
\end{equation}
\kant[5-10] % fill page 2 and go to page 3

% now we'd like the big display goes on page 3
\begin{figure*}
\begin{align}
zzzzzz &= zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz \\
uuuuuu &= uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu
\end{align}
\end{figure*}

\kant*[11]
\begin{equation}
c=c
\end{equation}
\kant[12-20]

\end{document}
```

Note the mismatch in the numbering.

In order to get the big display on page 3, we need to move the code for `figure*` back, so it falls between paragraphs that are typeset on page 2.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[numbers]{kantlipsum} % for mock text

\begin{document}

\title{A paper}
\author{A. Uthor}
\date{}

\maketitle

\kant[1-3] % fill page 1
\kant*[4]
\begin{equation} % an equation
a=a
\end{equation}
\kant[5]

% now we'd like the big display goes on page 3
\begin{figure*}
\begin{align}
zzzzzz &= zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz \\
uuuuuu &= uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu
\end{align}
\end{figure*}

\kant[6-10] % fill page 2 and go to page 3

\kant*[11]
\begin{equation}
c=c
\end{equation}
\kant[12-20]

\end{document}
```

However, the equation numbers could be off and you most likely want that equations on page 3 receive numbers that follow the ones in the display.

Identify the first paragraph in page 3 (here I use the option `numbers`, in a real document just look for the relevant text). OK, it's paragraph number 9.

Modify the text to step the `equation` counter at the spot, give `\label` there and use `\tag` in the display.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[numbers]{kantlipsum} % for mock text

\begin{document}

\title{A paper}
\author{A. Uthor}
\date{}

\maketitle

\kant[1-3] % fill page 1
\kant*[4]
\begin{equation} % an equation
a=a
\end{equation}
\kant[5]

\begin{figure*}
\begin{align}
zzzzzz &= zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz \tag{\ref{bigdisplayfirst}}\\
uuuuuu &= uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu \tag{\ref{bigdisplaysecond}}
\end{align}
\end{figure*}

\kant[6-8]

\refstepcounter{equation}\label{bigdisplayfirst}
\refstepcounter{equation}\label{bigdisplaysecond}


\kant[9-10] % fill page 2 and go to page 3

% now we'd like the big display goes on page 3

\kant*[11]
\begin{equation}
c=c
\end{equation}
\kant[12-20]

\end{document}
```

Maybe you're lucky and all goes well without this adjustment; in this case you can refrain from using the trick (that would ruin hyperlinks, if used).

Of course this has to be done when the document is, as far as the text is concerned, in final-no-more-changes-to-be-made-to-the-text form.